# Async task will not produce the good response

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous, task

I'm trying to wait the end of function to perform some task. HEre is my architecture

- A class for the windows service
- A class for communication with a device, instanciated as "ilon". This class have access to another class, who permit me to use a webservice

From the windows service, i'm doing it :

`Item_DataColl resultSet = ilon.read("Net/LON/10/LampDali1/nviRunHours");`

Here is the definition of the read function of the "ilon" class:

```
internal Item_DataColl read(string UCPTName)
{
       return ilonBind.invoke_command_READ("Net/LON/10/LampDali1/nviRunHours").Result;
}
```

Ilonbind variable is associated to a class who permit me to create a connection with the webservice. So he got a function named "invoke_command_read", defined as :

```
public async Task<Item_DataColl> invoke_command_READ(string UCPTName)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => thread_command_READ_result(UCPTName));
}
```

On the same class, i finally have this function :

```
private Item_DataColl thread_command_READ_result(string UCPTName)
{
    Item_DataColl resultSet = null;
    if (UCPTName != null)
    {
        try
        {
            OnProgressBarUpdate(progressBar.UnknownEnd);
            resultSet = connector.command_READ(UCPTName);
            readOperationDone(resultSet);
            OnConsoleWriting(string.Format("[READING] Lecture réussie : {0} = {1}", ((Dp_Data)resultSet.Item[0]).UCPTname, ((Dp_Data)resultSet.Item[0]).UCPTvalue[0].Value), ILonConnectorConsoleResultType.RESULT);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            OnConsoleWriting(e.ToString(), ILonConnectorConsoleResultType.ERROR);
        }
        finally
        {
            OnProgressBarUpdate(progressBar.Invisible);
        }
    }
    return resultSet;
}
```

Instruction "resultSet = connector.command_READ(UCPTName)" work well, and no result will be return until the result of the webservice request. But i am not able to get any result of the webservice.

Are my Task used well ?

Answer (score 1):

> Are my Task used well?

No.

Here's what's going on:

1. The actual operation is a network call, so it's a perfect fit for `async`.
2. But the proxy gives you synchronous APIs, so you're blocking a thread. (not good)
3. So `invoke_command_READ` wraps the synchronous API in a `Task.Run`, so it blocks a thread pool thread. (not good)
4. Then `read` blocks on the task using `Result`, blocking *two* threads per request and [causing a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). (really bad)

Your code is sync-over-async-over-sync, which is notable for employing *two* anti-patterns ([sync-over-async](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) and [async-over-sync](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)) simultaneously.

To fix this, either go async all the way, or sync all the way. Async all the way is more efficient but requires async APIs on your proxy:

```
public async Task<Item_DataColl> invoke_command_READ(string UCPTName)
{
  Item_DataColl resultSet = null;
  if (UCPTName != null)
  {
    try
    {
      OnProgressBarUpdate(progressBar.UnknownEnd);
      resultSet = await connector.command_READAsync(UCPTName);
      readOperationDone(resultSet);
      OnConsoleWriting(string.Format("[READING] Lecture réussie : {0} = {1}", ((Dp_Data)resultSet.Item[0]).UCPTname, ((Dp_Data)resultSet.Item[0]).UCPTvalue[0].Value), ILonConnectorConsoleResultType.RESULT);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      OnConsoleWriting(e.ToString(), ILonConnectorConsoleResultType.ERROR);
    }
    finally
    {
      OnProgressBarUpdate(progressBar.Invisible);
    }
  }
  return resultSet;
}

internal Task<Item_DataColl> readAsync(string UCPTName)
{
  return ilonBind.invoke_command_READ("Net/LON/10/LampDali1/nviRunHours");
}
```

Sync all the way would probably be easier, since your proxy is sync and your consuming code is sync:

```
internal Item_DataColl read(string UCPTName)
{
  return ilonBind.invoke_command_READ("Net/LON/10/LampDali1/nviRunHours");
}

public Item_DataColl invoke_command_READ(string UCPTName)
{
  return thread_command_READ_result(UCPTName);
}
```

Comment: Alright, so the API i use don't provide async API. So by using sync way, i'm trying to do like you said, but this will block the main thread, no ? I have to create something to run code on another thread and return me the result ?

Comment: @NFrb: Your original code was deliberately blocking the main thread. If you *don't* want to block the main thread, then you can use `await Task.Run`.

Comment: fine, i will start over this, i think it will be a better way to find a way out. I'll keep you abreast